# Space between two blocks

Tags: html, css, block, space

I encountered a problem where, in the following code-example a space is displayed between the red and black blocks.

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/WF5Ua/

I tried to change position, margin and etc., but I couldn't solve the trouble.

```
.slider {
    height:594px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#eb5055;
    border-bottom:6px solid #ea676b;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `display:inline-block;` in header

http://jsfiddle.net/WF5Ua/1/

Answer (score 0):

The space is because of `display:inline-block`.for `inline:block` defaultly a `4px` gap will be
 there.
You can remove that gap in so,many ways but one of my best is using `margin` and give
 as a value `-4px` or `font-size:0px`.
Rather than all this stuff you can use `float:left`.